# Unsynchronization and synchronization for NTP

Tags: networking, ntp

I am using a GPS source for my NTP server. I am using the *Meinberg* program for my NTP as well.

My NTP client configuration is:

```
Server ntpclock prefer iburst minpoll 2 maxpoll 5
```

If my NTP client is set 30 minutes or more back in time, is it really difficult to synchronise back? Because I have been testing with 5 minutes, 10 minutes and 15 minutes. But not 30 minutes and more.

If the synchronization takes longer time for the 30 minutes back in time and more, what would be the reason or explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Since in all examples the offset is greater than the step threshold of 128 ms, the clock should step in a little more than 10 mins (the step out threshold); how much more will depend on the current poll interval (2^2=4s to 2^5=32s) which depends on how stable it was before, and on when the clock fell out of synch relative to the polling.  iburst speeds up the sync after the step out threshold timer triggers.